# Swype flashing on and off

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, swype

I just upgraded my Samsung Galaxy SII phone, unlocked from Gingerbread to stock ICS (ver 4.0.3), and I think it looks cool in many aspects. One thing I am getting annoyed with though is the Swype. I used it all the time before, and it was amazing. What is happening now is that when I swype, get my list of suggestions, then I have about 2 seconds to click on the proper word before the suggestion list goes away, and my screen refreshes. This is killing the battery very fast, and is very annoying when typing longer messages. **Is there a way to set the suggestion bar to stay put like in Gingerbread?**

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and re-installing Swype yet?

Comment: @Chahk How do I do that?

Comment: I guess it depends if Swype came pre installed on your handset. In that case I don't think you can uninstall it. In either case, try going to Settings -> Apps and see if Swype is listed. Tap it and try to uninstall it. Then you can go to http://beta.swype.com, download the installer, install it, run it, and follow directions to sign in and install the beta.

Comment: @Chahk Built in app. Force Stopped it, then it worked properly for about a minute, and is back the way it was

Comment: Is this happening only within a particular app, or everywhere?  I've just noticed this behavior in Chrome browser on my Galaxy Nexus running a custom 4.1.1 ROM.  Other apps with text input (Google Voice, Gmail, Email, Google Talk, Trillian, Google+, TweetDeck, Tapatalk) don't seem to be impacted.

Comment: Every app... GMail, Browser, SMS

Comment: @Chahk I found the beta, installed it, and it seems to be working (over 2 weeks testing). Make that an answer and I'll mark it as such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Chahk's answer

> I guess it depends if Swype came pre installed on your handset. In that case I don't think you can uninstall it. In either case, try going to **Settings** -> **Apps** and see if Swype is listed. Tap it and try to uninstall it. Then you can go to [beta.swype.com](http://beta.swype.com), download the installer, install it, run it, and follow directions to sign in and install the beta.